# Jquery iterate over flask data passed into template

Tags: jquery, flask

I want to use jquery to iterate over flask db query results passed to template via render_template and add data to a html table, row by row. I can't figure out the proper jquery command to make it work! When I run the code it doesn't throw any errors, it just displays an empty table. There are 2 records in the db table.

db model:

```
class Cust(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'custs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

flask view:

```
@home.route('/')
def homepage():
    custs = Cust.query.all()
    return render_template('home/index.html', title="Home", custs=custs)
```

template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < '{{ custs|length }}') {
        var name = custs[i].name;
        var age = custs[i].age;
        $('#table1 > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + age + '</td></tr>');
        i++;
    } 
});

</script>
```

But if I run my script as:

```
$(function() {
            var name = custs[0].name;
            var age = custs[0].age;
            $('#table1 > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + age + '</td></tr>');
    });
```

My table will populate with the first record!

Ok, for anyone else who may run into this issue here's how I did it!

```
$(function() {
    {% for c in custs %}
        var name = '{{ c.name }}';
        var age = '{{ c.age }}';
        $('#table1 > tbody').append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + age + '</td></tr>');
    {% endfor %}
});
```

It now iterates over the query variable and loads the data into the table correctly.

Thanks @Kata Csortos, for answering, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about iterating over custs like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    for (const cust of custs) {
        const name = cust.name;
        const age = cust.age;
        $('#table1 > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + age + '</td></tr>');
    } 
});

</script>
```

Or pass the lenght of custs as a variable to jinja and iterate through the elements of custs with a for loop.